# Is the algorithmic problem for regular languages decidable?

Tags: automata, regular-language, decidability

I have an algorithmic problem, where I need to build an algorithm and say if the problem is decidable. Here it is:

> Regular languages $L_1$, $L_2$, and $L_3$ are given by finite automata. Is the problem decidable?
> $$\exists v \in L_1, \forall w \in L_2, \quad vw \in L_3.$$

I'm new to regular languages and finite automatons, so I don't understand how to do it. Can you help me to build this algorithm and give some useful links to read more about these themes?

Comment: When you say solvable, do you mean decidable or semi-decidable?

Comment: @ronno I meant decidable, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suffices to (decidably) construct a finite automaton for the language
$$L = \{v \mid vL_2 \subset L_3\}$$
since then the problem reduces to deciding if the regular language $L \cap L_1 \ne \varnothing$, which amounts to reachability in a DFA/NFA. Consider a DFA $\mathcal{A}$ for $L_3$ with states $Q$. Now, given $q \in Q$, let $L_q$ be the regular language recognized by the DFA $\mathcal{A}_q$ which is the same as $\mathcal{A}$ except with start state $q$. Let $F = \{q \in Q \mid L_2 \subset L_q\}$. Note that $F$ is decidable by the same reachability argument, since $L_2 \subset L_q \iff L_2 \cap L_q^c = \varnothing$. But now $L$ is recognized by the DFA which is the same as $\mathcal{A}$ but with accepting states $F$.

Comment: What if regular language $L_2$ is infinite? Then it's not possible to construct a finite automaton for $L$.

Comment: @VladyslavChobotok I think you are confused. A regular language is, by definition, one for which there exists a finite state automaton.

Comment: @MarkSaving A regular language can be either finite or infinite (set of strings). If $L_2$ is infinite, then it may not be possible to construct such an automaton, as it may require an infinite number of states or am I wrong?

Comment: @VladyslavChobotok It depends on your definition of regular language, but it is either by definition or a basic fact about regular language that, finite or infinite, they are exactly languages defined by acceptance of finite state automata. For example, wikipedia has [an image of a (deterministic) finite automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine#/media/File:DFAexample.svg) that recognizes binary strings with even number of 0s, which is definitely an infinite language.

Comment: @VladyslavChobotok Also note that the problem says that the languages $L_1$, $L_2$, $L_3$ come with given finite automata.

Comment: @ronno thanks, now I got it